# Amazon linux install openvpn3-client

Tags: unix, openvpn, amazon-linux

Trying to install openvpn3-client on my amazon Linux followed [this](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN3Linux) documentation, facing below error

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    openvpn3-13-0.beta1.el7.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:dsommers:openvpn3
    openvpn3-client-13-0.beta1.el7.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:dsommers:openvpn3
    openvpn3-selinux-13-0.beta1.el7.noarch from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:dsommers:openvpn3
    python36-dbus-1.2.4-4.el7.x86_64 from epel
    python36-gobject-base-3.22.0-6.el7.x86_64 from epel
```

I have already installed epel following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon linux install openvpn3-client & dependencies as per
https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux

> See the instructions on
> https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN3Linux how to
> install pre-built OpenVPN 3 Linux packages on Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora,
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS and Scientific Linux.

1 solution was to switch from AWS Linux (lack of dependencies & updates) to Fedora on AWS. No longer have to build from source / add dependancices,
older versions had to add the repo as per the above.
When I did an upgrade to Fedora 36 the latest openvpn3-linux v18 client was built in. Did not have to manually upgrade / install it:

```
openvpn3-admin version --services
```

e.g: previous v17 suddenly stopped working spend 10 hours trying to debug
"Trying to install openvpn3-client" and reinstall:

```
openvpn3 config-import --config profile.udp.ovpn --persistent
openvpn3 config-manage --config profile.udp.ovpn --enable-legacy-algorithms true --show
openvpn3 session-start --config profile.udp.ovpn
openvpn3 sessions-list 
openvpn3 session-manage --config profile.udp.ovpn --disconnect
```

Actually thinking it was a `cipher AES-256-CBC` legacy issue that others were having. It was not for some reason, permissions on install of the OpenVPN3 Linux client? as it was NOT creating a **TUN**.
So [I made one myself](https://www.naturalborncoder.com/virtualization/2014/10/17/understanding-tun-tap-interfaces) (that was the actual issue) and it connected after asking for VPN Username & Password, no need to install again / reinstall afterall:

```
sudo ip tuntap add name tun0 mode tun
sudo ip link show
```

Other Amazon linux install openvpn3-client issues help is here: https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux/issues?q=cipher